# Two categories of scales

Tags: scales, terminology

There are scales like C-Major or Eb harmonic Minor or A-octatonic or G# Mixo(#11) or E-acoustic. Heck, what not, a plenty of scales actually, more you could imagine to be listed here.

And there are the dodecaphonic or chromatic scale, there are 12-EDO scales, 39-EDO scales, 5-limit just-tempered scales etc. If I were entitled to coin terms for existing things, I would not call these "scales" both but this and that both concepts are actually the same is claimed by some loose online contact of mine, given there is no mere misunderstanding.
Also, both types of scales could be defined in the SCALA format they say.

If there is indeed one term "scale" for both types, aren't there any neat adjectives to tell them apart in dialogues among anglesaxon music theory nerds?

One could argue that the latter category are not scales but tuning systems. However, once applied in some musical context, especially the just tunings would need, however, a prime tone because both the prime tone and the reference tone (say, A4=440Hz) determine the pitches of all the member tones so they match the set n-limit intervals. Whatever the prime tone, I assume it can have one of several pitches depending on the number of steps to the reference tone A4.
If there is a prime and an octave at the other end, we can call it a scale, don't we?

Comment: Would you argue the whole tone scale fits in the former or the latter?

Comment: "One could argue that the latter category are not scales but tuning systems." Yes, I would. One distinction here is between *names* and *descriptors*. You could have a "C major scale"—that names and identifies an entity. You could also speak of "a rapid scale," "a scale in parallel thirds," etc.; these are not specific entities, just descriptions. To my mind the latter category is like this.

Comment: In my eyes whole-tone scale would be the former type as that one too is based or layered upon another scale (12-EDO, chromatic, dodecaphonic, whatever you name the underlying scale), avoiding, "tabooing" every other discrete step of it.

Comment: @musiclanger - Weird, I was about to argue the latter since the whole tone scale is arguably 6TET (at least as much as the chromatic scale is 12TET, which is to say that neither of them may be quite there).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a question about musical jargon. Language questions like this often have two aspects that can be usefully teased apart.

The first is **descriptive** -- we would like to know how people in fact use the term "scale". Certainly I've seen it used in both senses you describe: a gamut of notes with an appointed "root note" or "tonic", and a tuning system such as 31EDO. As with many other words that can have multiple meanings, we rely on context to remove the ambiguity.

The second is **prescriptive** -- how *should* these terms be used when we want to be precise and avoid any ambiguity? This is a matter of preference -- but not just *your* preference. Since you'll be communicating with others, you have to take account of their preferences, too.

For my part, where ambiguity is possible, I prefer to keep "tuning" or "tuning system" for the *set of notes that are available for musical use* and "scale" for *a selection of those notes, one of which is distinguished as the root note*. But I understand that this usage isn't universal, so some negotiation might be needed.

Your point about non-equal tunings that are generated from a "base note" is very interesting, but probably belongs to a different question (which I wouldn't be in a great position to answer).

Comment: If a tuning system is a set of notes available for use then some tuning systems are infinite -- particularly just intonation of any "limit."  Have I got that right?

Comment: @phoog A just intonation usually has 12 notes in the octave but they're not equally spaced. A tuning literally containing an infinite set of notes would be possible in theory but probably not useful since we couldn't distinguish between all the notes aurally. Of course almost all music does also use (infinite) *continuous* pitch space alongside tunings. Someone else might be able to express this better than I have though.

Comment: So I should prefer the well-established terms "key" to the former and "intonation" / "tuning system" to the latter category, no matter if the tones are seen as an ordered sequence and a "root note" can be marked in both. In fact, they both can be regarded as "scales", but this does not necessarily qualify "scale" to be the common denominator of the categorization. That would suggest, by the way, chords on the one hand and the natural harmonic series on the other hand be scales in an analogous manner. So I've put my mental concept in proper order and my problem is kind of solved, thank you all.

Answer (score 2):

A scale is basically any set of notes portrayed in an organised manner. Hence ascending and descending. How else could a set of notes which belong together be shown?

So it doesn't really matter which those notes are, or what the scale gets labelled, that's the way those notes get written to be played.

Scale - adjective - *scalar* - simply means steps. As one would scale a ladder, a wall, a flight of steps. Get to the top, return. Using the same set backwards. Apologies here for classical melodic minor - the only fly in the ointment, for several reasons - most important being the fact that it's called 'melodic'!

Comment: "So it doesn't really matter which those notes are, or what the scale gets labelled, that's the way those notes get written to be played." As soon as it gets to play notes you need to deal with intonation. So, how does a given scale relate to intonation? Is it rather agnostic or is it even characterized by a specific intonation/temperament/tuning?

Comment: @musiclanger requirements of intonation vary widely depending on the context.  Commonly, except in the case of keyboards and other truly fixed-pitch instruments, the scale defines several pitch classes that are actually ranges of acceptable frequency.  With different temperaments, you can have several different variations of the C major scale; they're all still C major scales.

Comment: Exactly. But a specific intonation is a property not of C major scale, is it? It is rather a property of the underlying 12-tone-scale that can be 12-EDO, just 5-limit, or any scale tempered to a historical tuning system. Assuming an acoustic piano tuner would tune all 12 keys of the octave except if you, say, short of money, explicitly ask for the white ones only, restricting yourself to C-major and its parallel modes. In my mind I somehow happened to stick to a stacking concept of intonation-agnostic scales over intonation dependent with more steps.